# How to create a xml file at a particular location from the output generated from jsp page

Tags: html, xml, jsp

sports.jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
<% response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"playlist.xml\""); %>
<playlist version="1" xmlns = "http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
   <title>My Band Rocks Your Socks</title>
   <trackList>
   <%! String[] sports; %>
   <%
      sports = request.getParameterValues("sports");
      if (sports != null)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < sports.length; i++)
         {
            // out.println (sports[i]);
            String total=sports[i];
            String[] sa=total.split("[,]");
            // String[] sub=new String();
            out.print("<track>");
            for (int j=0;j<sa.length;j++)
            {
               // out.println(sa[j]);
               // out.println("sa["+j+"]="+sa[j]);
               if( j == 0)
               {
                  out.print("<location>" + sa[0] +"</location>");
               }
               else if (j == 1)
               {
                  out.print("<image>" + sa[1] +"</image>");
               }
               else if( j==2)
               {
                  out.print("<title>" + sa[2] +"</title>");
               }
            }// end of inner for loop()
            out.print("</track>");
            //out.println();
         }// end of outer for()
      }
      //else out.println ("<b>none<b>");
   %>
   </trackList>
</playlist>
```

This code is generating an xml file, but it is prompting me to mention the location where to save it.I want to create and store xml file at a particular location without any prompting and each time for the next input values the current xml file should be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for a feature that no browser wants to provide, due to security risks.  You don't want a browser to be able to overwrite an arbitrary file on the system with no user prompt.

If you really need to do this, you need to be running a signed Applet or Web Start application.  With this, you have permission to write locally without a user prompt.  If you don't want to purchase an official certificate, you can use a self-signed certificate to sign your JAR files.  If you do this, the user will get a prompt when they encounter your application about the certificate.  However, once the Applet/Web Start application is running, you have free reign to write locally.

Note:  You need to edit your question to insert four blanks in front of each line of your JSP, so it will be correctly and automatically formatted by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that due to security restrictions. You cannot get access of user system and start writing files without user's permission.